# returning empty list, append did not work

Tags: python, list

The question being:

The email_list function receives a dictionary, which contains domain names as keys, and a list of users as values. Fill in the blanks to generate a list that contains complete email addresses (e.g. diana.prince@gmail.com).

[image: output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYydB.png)

```
def email_list(domains):
emails = []
domains = {}
for domain, group in domains.items():
  for names in group:
    emails.append(names + "@" + group)
return(emails)

print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))
```

**Did lots of debugging to get here, earlier the code won't even execute; what might i be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

this worked...

```py
def email_list(domains):
    emails = []
    for domain, users in domains.items():
          for user in users:
              emails.append(user+'@'+domain)
    return(emails)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code provided**

```
def email_list(domains):
emails = []
domains = {}     
for domain, group in domains.items():
  for names in group:
    emails.append(names + "@" + group)
return(emails)  #not including print statement here
```

***Error in the provided code***

1. It is already mentioned in the question that domain is already a dictionary so there's no need to declare it again as from then onwards python will consider the word "domain" associated to an empty dictionary
2. The correct append statement should be like:-
   `emails.append(str(user) +'@' +str(domain))`
   #domain--> the name of key you've declared

***Correct code***

```
def email_list(domains):
emails = []
for domain, group in domains.items():
  for names in group:
    emails.append(str(names) + "@" + str(domain))
return(emails)

print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))
```

*Hope it helps :)*

Answer (score 0):

You did everything wrong.

Why did you reassign the parameter `domains` to empty?

```
domains = {}
```

And append string without domain:

```
emails.append(names + "@" + group)
```

Everything is so simple, just debug every lines.

Comment: till the time i didn't declare domains = {}; i was getting errors that it was unidentified, post which i was able to access domains.values();
I will try once again to follow through and domain in append

Answer (score 0):

.using domains.items() returned tuples then uesd
.for user in users:
.email = user,"@",domain
.emails.append(''.join(email))
. then used above to iterate the users from list and added then using .join() .function

```
def email_list(domains):
    emails = []
    for domain, users in domains.items():
      for user in users:
          email = user,"@",domain
          emails.append(''.join(email))
          
          
    return(emails)

print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.